# Replacing all path string in a file with sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have an xml file with tons and tons of absolute path strings (e.g. `/home/matt/somefolder/somefile.c`) . I want to replace them all with relative address(`./somefile.c`). my script looks like this and it doesn't seem to be replacing the path strings

```
tmp=`pwd`
cat a.xml | sed 's/$tmp/.' > a.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
tmp=$(pwd)
sed "s#$tmp#.#" a.xml > a2.xml
```

Note the double quotes to make sure that `$tmp` is substituted. And since path includes slashes it's better to use different character (`#` in this case) for sed.

Comment: This should be rewritten.  #1, do not use `cat` with program that can read data itself like `sed`.  #2. Do not use old and outdated backtics, use parentheses. So this would then be: `tmp=$(pwd)` and `sed "s#$tmp#.#" a.xml > a2.xml`

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment. I have updated my answer with your suggestions.